# jQuery - console.log delivers empty array if evaluated at the end of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Having an array `temp1` with this pattern:

```
[{"group":"Test","keywords":["Hund","Katze"]}]
```

I'm able to make API requests for getting synonyms of each element of `temp1.keywords` with the following function:

```
consultSynonyms(temp1)

    function consultSynonyms(x) {
        // create an empty array where all the responses are gping to be pushed
        // format has to be: [{x: xvalue, y: yvalue, z:zvalue...}]. This array
        // will be passed to data table plugin
        var jsonSynonyms = [];
        $.each(x, function(i, value) {
            // get name of group (f.i. Test)
            var superGroup = value.group;
            $.each(x[i].keywords, function(i, value) {
                // get term (f.i. Hund) and iterate all the terms
                var term = value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/search?q=" + term + "&format=application/json&supersynsets=true",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data.synsets, function(key, value) {
                            // get category (f.i. "Biology") from response
                            var category = this.categories[0];
                            $.each(this.terms, function(key, value) {
                                // synonym is every term delievered by the API Call
                                // level is also delievered (f.i.: "formal", "informal"...)
                                var synonym = this.term;
                                var level = this.level;
                                jsonSynonyms.push({
                                    group: superGroup,
                                    keyword: term,
                                    category: category,
                                    term: synonym,
                                    level: level
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(jsonSynonyms);
    }
```

However, the last `console.log` doesn´t deliver the expected output but a simple `[]`. I am sure that the ajax code is correct, because if I move the console.log inside the `function(data)`, I get the expected output:

```
[{"group":"Unnamed group","keyword":"Hund","category":"Biologie","term":"Hund"},{"group":"Unnamed group","keyword":"Hund","category":"Biologie","term":"Vierbeiner"}...]
```

As far as I'm corcerned, the console.log at the end of my function is evaluated at the very end, and therefore I don't understand why I'm getting the blank array, while evaluating it at the middle of the function delivers a correct output. Any hint for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an AJAX request which begins asycnchronous execution of the code inside it. And once you go async, ***you never go back***.

You see, `jsonSynonyms` won't be populated until *after* the AJAX call comes back. That may be any amount of time, probably 100-200ms. However, your `console.log(jsonSynonyms)` code executes *immediately* after the AJAX call is made. So `jsonSynonyms` could not have been populated.

You can only use the populated `jsonSynonyms` *after* the AJAX call has come back. That means you should use it within the actual AJAX callback.

```
function consultSynonyms(x) {
        // create an empty array where all the responses are gping to be pushed
        // format has to be: [{x: xvalue, y: yvalue, z:zvalue...}]. This array
        // will be passed to data table plugin
        var jsonSynonyms = [];
        $.each(x, function(i, value) {
            // get name of group (f.i. Test)
            var superGroup = value.group;
            $.each(x[i].keywords, function(i, value) {
                // get term (f.i. Hund) and iterate all the terms
                var term = value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/search?q=" + term + "&format=application/json&supersynsets=true",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data.synsets, function(key, value) {
                            // get category (f.i. "Biology") from response
                            var category = this.categories[0];
                            $.each(this.terms, function(key, value) {
                                // synonym is every term delievered by the API Call
                                // level is also delievered (f.i.: "formal", "informal"...)
                                var synonym = this.term;
                                var level = this.level;
                                jsonSynonyms.push({
                                    group: superGroup,
                                    keyword: term,
                                    category: category,
                                    term: synonym,
                                    level: level
                                });
                            });
                        });

                        console.log(jsonSynonyms); // look at me now!
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    }
```